# Dynamic Facebook Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am attempting to create a facebook share button on Page-A that will post a dynamic unique link to Page-B.  I have accomplished this however I am unable to control the image that the post shows.  When using the button on Page-A the post shows correctly, however once posted the image is of a completely different image found on Page-B.  I have included the following on both Page-A and Page-B.  (note the extra # is because of cold fusion escaping)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb##">

<meta property="og:title" content="PaceButler Referral Program" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="PaceButler" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.pacebutler.com/referral.cfm?Referalcode=#GetProfile.referralCode#" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The lifeblood of our business is New Customers. When you refer a New Customer to PaceButler, we'll pay you what we pay them for the 1st shipment of cell phones they send in (see Program Details). This is an easy way to make some real money!" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.pacebutler.com/images/referral/PB-Referral-Logo-Large.png" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found was that after a few days facebook did eventually clear the images that it had stored in its cache.